# Strawberry Perl installation of Encode::JIS2K fails

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I have installed the newest version of Strawberry Perl and installed several modules without any errors. However, the module Encode::JIS2K is stubbornly failing to install:

```
C:\PDFCrop\biblatex-biber-2.15>cpan Encode::JIS2K
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.219)
Database was generated on Tue, 15 Sep 2020 09:41:42 GMT
Running install for module 'Encode::JIS2K'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.096)
Checksum for C:\Strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\D\DA\DANKOGAI\Encode-JIS2K-0.03.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.38)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.82)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20200717)
Configuring D/DA/DANKOGAI/Encode-JIS2K-0.03.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
enc2xs not found! at Makefile.PL line 35.
Warning: No success on command[C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]
  DANKOGAI/Encode-JIS2K-0.03.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Encode::JIS2K'.
```

I believe that `enc2xs not found! at Makefile.PL line 35.` is the problematic entry, but I am at a loss why there is something missing since all actions before returned "OK" and it worked for every other module so far.

Working on Windows 10, x64 with Strawberry Perl v. 5.32.0.1

Comment: [enc2xs](https://metacpan.org/source/DANKOGAI/Encode-3.07/bin/enc2xs) if part of [Encode](http://p3rl.org/Encode)

Comment: @choroba Thank you, but how do I remedy the problem. I tried `cpan Encode::enc2xs` but that gives me a `Skipping Encode::enc2xs because I couldn't find a matching namespace.`

Comment: Encode should be already installed as its a core module.

Comment: @choroba Ok, so is there any possibility to test specifically if that is the case or add otherwise remedy the situation without reinstalling everything and hoping for the best?

Comment: I checked and there are two files, `enc2xs` and `enc2xs.bat` in the "Strawberry/perl/bin" folder. Only it seems, Strawberry Perl does not find them...

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf The problem seems to have been discussed earlier at PerlMonks, see [this](https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=11108936) thread.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thank you, that solved my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you find a problem like that, it's always worth checking to see if it's a known problem. You can do that by visiting [the module's page on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::JIS2K). You can then click on [the "Issues" link](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Encode-JIS2K) in the left-hand menu.

You'll see there's an issue entitled [enc2xs may not be found on MSWIN32](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=110069) which is about the problem you've found.

Unfortunately, that problem has been there, unfixed, for five years. However, the problem description includes a suggested fix for the problem. You can edit your Makefile.PL and replace lines 34-35 with this:

```
$enc2xs = $enc2xs_fpath
   if (-x $enc2xs_fpath || -x "$enc2xs_fpath.bat");
```